# Firestore and Unicode

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The documentation describes that Firestore supports Unicode. You just need to insert already formatted text into Firestore. But when unloading, the following are not taken into account:

1. Line break;
2. Unicode characters inserted directly into the text (eg `\u000a`).
   The code is below.
   Repository

```kotlin
    suspend fun getData(): Response<List<Model>> =
        suspendCoroutine { cont ->
            val collection =
                firestore
                    .collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
                    .whereEqualTo(DEFAULT_CONDITION_FIELD, DEFAULT_CONDITION_VALUE)
                    .orderBy(SORT_FIELD, SORT_DIRECTION)
                    .get()

            collection
                .addOnSuccessListener { query ->
                    val data = arrayListOf<Model>()
                    query.toObjects(ModelDomain::class.java).forEach { data.add(it.toModel()) }
                    cont.resume(Response.Success(data))
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { cont.resume(Response.Error(it)) }
        }
```

ViewModel

```kotlin
    private val _data: LiveData<Response<List<Model>>> = loadData()
    val data get() = _data

    private fun loadData(): LiveData<Response<List<Model>>> =
        liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Response.Loading)

            try {
                emit(repository.getData())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emit(Response.Error(e))
            }
        }
```

Model

```kotlin
data class ModelDomain(
    var description: String = ""
) : KoinComponent {
    fun toModel() =
        Model(
            description = description
        )
}

data class Model(
    val description: String
)
```

Part of the code has been omitted.

**UPDATE**

Just wrote in Notepad ++:

[image]

Copied this to Firestore:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firestore does not, in any way, modify data that you write to it.  If you write something to a document, then read the document, you will get exactly the same data that you put into it.

If you're looking at the document *in the Firebase console*, you will not see all carriage returns and whitespace.  Those are collapsed to save space on screen when rendering large amounts of data.  But if you read the data programmatically, it will definitely be exactly as you wrote it.

Comment: Again, the console collapses data.  You should read and write the document **programmatically** to make it work correctly with carriage return characters.  Copying and pasting from the console is not that.

Comment: Now it is clear. To get correct data, you need to enter them programmatically. Is it possible to implement this without writing additional functionality (the application is tailored for a feed reference book)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You will have to write code to get reads and writes to work with any data.